# Guidelines for good webcrawler 'Etiquette'

Tags: web-crawler

I'm building a search engine (for fun) and it has just struck me that potentially my little project might wreak havok by clicking on ads and all sorts of problems.

**So what are the guidelines for good webcrawler 'Etiquette'?**

Things that spring to mind:

1. Observe Robot.txt instructions
2. Limit the number of simultaneous requests to the same domain
3. Don't follow ad links?

**Stopping the crawler from clicking on ads**
 - This one is particularly on my mind at the moment... how do i stop my bot from 'clicking' on ads? if it is going straight to the url in the ad is it counted as a click?

Comment: Does anyone have good resources for Finding and Parsing a domains robot.txt?

Comment: http://www.robotstxt.org/ is the de facto reference.  It appears to be blocked from where I work, though, so I can't verify that.  A certain sort of irony, since we make webapps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't read only the robots.txt instruction. You should also see the [meta tags with noindex and nofollow](http://www.linktutorial.com/read/articles/meta-tags-noindexnofollow).

About the ad question, I'm not sure, but I guess if you just read the links and then some other time enter the page, the entered page will have no info on how you got that address, and can't charge the site for the "pseudoclick"

Answer (score 2):

Don't follow links marked as rel="nofollow".

Also, you don't have to worry about ads. If you spider only HTML text of a page, then in most cases you won't get ad links there - they are generated on client using javascript.